# Adding dependencies to the android library 'api' vs 'implementation'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Let's assume that I'm creating Android library and want to use ConstraintLayout. I see two different approaches by other lib creators:
1. Add it with `implementation` keyword. The downside is if someone adds my lib to project and doesn't have constraint-layout in dependencies the build will fail with errors like that: `error: attribute 'com.example.test:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' not found.`
2. Add it with 'api'. That way it compiles fine, but if any other library uses constraint-layout with other versions it can produce error `Android dependency 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.1.2)`

Which way has the lowest maintenance cost for the clients code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the lowest maintenance cost for the client code. It's about whether the client needs the transitive dependency — `ConstraintLayout` — in order to *compile* against your library. Whether you use `implementation` or `api`, the transitive dependency will always be a *runtime* dependency of the client.

Here's the question you need to ask yourself: are you using `ConstraintLayout` or any other elements of the transitive library in the method signatures or properties of your library's public API, i.e. the stuff that's used by the client? If yes, then you should declare the constraint layout library as `api`. Otherwise, use `implementation`.